# How to use jquery.min in react with webpack

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack

Can somebody help on how to use jquery.min in React Components.

Using the below increases the bundle size, where core jquery is loaded.

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

I would like to use the minified version of jquery which is less in size.

Comment: Are you using `webpack -p`? It should pack a minified version that is roughly the same size as the original `jquery.min.js`

Comment: thanks. yes i am using webpack .. i could see that it takes jquery.js from the node_modules folder ... even after using webpack .. generated bundle analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

You can require the minified version directly:

```
var $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min');
```

However, a more common solution is to run webpack in production mode (`webpack -p`) or use a plugin like [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) to minify your entire bundle (including both your own source code and libraries like jQuery) before you deploy your application to production.

Comment: Dan thanks. i do use uglify webpack. even after that i analyzed with bundleanalyzer  where jquery stands at 252kb . but  jquery.min is only 82kb.